# merging multiple attribute nodes with same value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Can you please help me on how to do this xml:
    The xml looks like

```
    <a name="hr_1" id="hr">
    <text>11</text>
    </a>
    <a name="hr_2" id="hr">
    <text>12</text>
    </a>

    <a name="hre_1" id ="hre">
    <text>11</text>
    </a>
    <a name="hre_2" id ="hre">
    <text>12</text>
    </a>
```

expected output:The transformed output is expected like below

```
    <b name ="hr">
    <value>11</value>
    <value>12</value>
    </b>

    <b name ="hre">
    <value>11</value>
    <value>12</value>
    </b>
```

Comment: Can you explain the rules to merge those `a` elements or their `text` children? Is that based on the `text` value? Also, which XSLT version do you use/can you use?

Comment: it is based on the name, so all value for hr_1,hr_2 .. etc need to be combined... similarly all values for hre_1,hre_2.. etc.. need to be combined. xslt 1.2

Comment: Can you explain the expected structure of the `name` attribute? Do you want to group by `substring-before(@name, '_')`? But where in your expected output are the merged values for the `hre_x` elements?

Comment: yes, absolutely correct

Comment: Is your expected output correct then, as it is missing an entry for name "hre". Thanks!

Comment: yeah, thanks for pointing... <b name ="hr">
    <value>11</value>
    <value>12</value>
    </b> <b name ="hre">
    <value>11</value>
    <value>12</value>
    </b>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comment:

> Thank you so much... How can i do it in xslt 1.0.. Also i added one
>   more tag id, so i need to group based on id.Please help in xslt 1.0

In XSLT 1.0, use [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). What I would do is create a key matching all `text` elements and using the `id` attribute of the parent...

**XML**

```
<doc>
    <a name="hr_1" id="hr">
        <text>11</text>
    </a>
    <a name="hr_2" id="hr">
        <text>12</text>
    </a>    
    <a name="hre_1" id ="hre">
        <text>11b</text>
    </a>
    <a name="hre_2" id ="hre">
        <text>12b</text>
    </a>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="kText" match="text" use="../@id"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="*/text[count(.|key('kText',../@id)[1])=1]">
        <b name="{../@id}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kText',../@id)"/>
        </b>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<doc>
   <b name="hr">
      <text>11</text>
      <text>12</text>
   </b>
   <b name="hre">
      <text>11b</text>
      <text>12b</text>
   </b>
</doc>
```

Comment: Thank .. can you help to explain how both text nodes get copied inside the same b tag... i can not understand how <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kText',../@id)"/> copied both the text node inside the b tag

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a simple grouping task then, solvable in XSLT 2 or 3 with `xsl:for-each-group`:

```
  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="a" group-by="substring-before(@name, '_')">
              <b name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/*"/>
              </b>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Assumes `root` is the common container element for the `a` elements to be grouped, adapt that as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much... How can i do it in xslt 1.0.. Also i added one more tag id, so i need to group based on id.Please help in xslt 1.0